# How to write an advanced function to select path and sort files?

Tags: powershell, sorting, path

```
function Sort-Size {  
   
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    param (  
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        [string] $Name

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]  
        $Path,  
        $Lenght 
    )  
      
    begin {  
        $Lenght = @() 
        
    }  
      
    process {  
          
        $Path = Get-ChildItem -recurse -File $Name
        
    }  
      
    end {  
        $Path | Select-Object FullName, @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={$_.Length/1KB}} | Sort-Object -Property FileSizeInKb | Format-Table -AutoSize 
    }  
}  
Sort-Size -Name  {Test-Path -Name "C:\"}
```

This code only sorts in one folder, how to make it sort in different folders?

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't need parameters `Name` and `Length`.
Instead, I would add an optional file pattern to look for and add a switch whether or not you want the function to recurse through the various subfolders.

Also, I would not have it return the DISPLAY ONLY output of `Format-Table`, but the sorted list of files itself. Then when caling the function you can decide if you want to pipe that to Format-* or do something else with the data.

Something like below:

```
function Sort-Size {  
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    param (   
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({ $_ | Test-Path -PathType Container })]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path,
    
        [string]$Pattern = '*.*',
        [switch]$Recurse
    )  
    Write-Verbose "Searching files in '$Path' with pattern '$Pattern'"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Filter $Pattern -Recurse:$Recurse | 
    Select-Object Name, DirectoryName, @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={[Math]::Round($_.Length/1KB, 2)}} | 
    Sort-Object FileSizeInKb
}  

Sort-Size -Path "C:\Users\user" | Format-Table -Property Name,FileSizeInKb -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Sort-Size {  
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    param (   
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]  
        $Path,  
        $Lenght,
        $Name
    )  
      
    begin {  
        $Lenght = @() 
        
    }  
      
    process {  
          
        $Path = Get-ChildItem -recurse -File "$Name"
        
    }  
      
    end {  
        $Path | Select-Object FullName, @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={$_.Length/1KB}} | Sort-Object -Property FileSizeInKb | Format-Table -AutoSize 
    }  
}  

#Sort-Size -Path "C:\Users"
Sort-Size -Name "C:\Users\user" 
#Get-Help "Sort-size"
```

Comment: your `end` block is sorting a single element